# Open Dialog Fragment onClick of child element of an ExpanandableListView

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I am a beginner in android and stuck with which I suppose is a simple task.

I have an `ExpandableListView` and a `DialogFragment` class. I want to initiate the dialogFragment class when I click the TextView element inside the `childView` of the List

Below is the `getChildView` method of `ExpandableListView`

```
public class TestList extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<String> headers;
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String> > > list_children;
    private Context context;

    private static final String DIALOG_SINGLE_CHOICE_LIST = "MainActivity.RepeatSettings";

.......

    @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) this.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
            if(convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
            }

            TextView repeat_btn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.repeat_btn);
            repeat_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RepeatSettings repeatSettings = new RepeatSettings();
                    repeatSettings.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_SINGLE_CHOICE_LIST );
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }

.....

}
```

In the above code I get an error,

> Cannot resolve method `getSupportFragmentManager()`

I know that my `TestList` class doesn't extend the `FragmentActivity` class, but I cannot do that because it already extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

I have also tried to use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` but here also I get an alert that an `Activity` class can't have a `getActivity()` method which is obvious as it will be for a `Fragment`.

Below is the code for Dialog class

```
public class RepeatSettings extends DialogFragment {

    String repeat_interval[] ;
    String selected_interval;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // creating an alertDialog object
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        //defining the repeat_interval string
       repeat_interval = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.repeat_interval);

        //setting the alert dialog title and the type of items contained in it.
        //First parameter is the list, second is the already checked item, third is the listner object
        builder.setTitle("Choose Repeat Interval").setSingleChoiceItems(repeat_interval, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        selected_interval = (String) repeat_interval[which];
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        selected_interval = (String) repeat_interval[which];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        selected_interval = (String) repeat_interval[which];
                }
            }
        }).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

How do I solve the above problem.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an Static new Instance method in the Dialog fragment class

```
 public static RepeatSettings newInstance() {
RepeatSettings frag = new RepeatSettings();
 return frag;
}
```

Then in your list adapter call the dialog fragment like this: Since your MainActivity activity's context is passed to the adapter.

```
RepeatSettings obj =  RepeatSettings.newInstance();

obj.show(((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_SINGLE_CHOICE_LIST);
```

Comment: Also see that you have imported "android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment" and not "android.app.DialogFragment". The later takes getFragmentManager and not getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: Yep I have imported `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` only. Also when I try your solution it gives me an error cannot resolve method DialogFragmentEditProfile . It should have a return type right

Comment: Still an error cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager . Also what does you context refer to here.

Comment: Still doesn't resolve getSupportFragmentManager(). As I said, is it because my AlarmList activity doesn't extends Fragment class

Comment: if your testList is  an activity just call getSupportFragmentManager.. But Since I think it's not an activity, you need to pass the context of the activity that implements the adapter.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, my TestList class extends BaseExpandableListAdapter, so it isn't an activity, I call getSupportFragmentManager as context.getSupportFragmentManager but it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131304/discussion-between-nishan-khadka-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: Thanks fro Help : ) . Appreciate it a lot, I was struggling on this for more than 2 days now